# validity of passports after stamped deported

Tags: india

if a person is deported from a country where he used to work to the country of his origin and his passport has been stamped DEPORTED   IS the passport still valid for visit to other countries

Answer (score 1):

A foreign government has no authority to revoke a a passport, so the passport is certainly valid.  The bearer of the passport will however find it more difficult to gain entry to other countries because the prior deportation will subject the bearer to greater scrutiny from visa officers and border guards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you can get a visa for the other country.

Even if you're considered visa-free (get entry clearance upon arrival) for a particular country, the immigration officers of that country could still deny you entry based on the prior deportation.